# Can't get background-image url of div and replace with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, background

I am making a lightbox, when an image wit the lightboxtrigger class is clicked it will be displayed a bigger size.

This is what I am doing:
when an image with the lightboxtrigger class is clicked I store the url into an array without all the invalid characters and then I replace I switch the src of the lightbox modal with the array.

I cant seem to get this to work, any idea why the tiny script I am using doesn't properly replace the string?

Here is my code:

```js
<script>

$('.triggerlightbox').click(function(){
var e=$(this);
var bg = e.css("background-image");
bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
$('.photogallery__viewer__image').html('<img src="' + bg + '" />');
});

</script>
```

```css
.photogallery__maincontainer{  width:1300px; height:580px; ; flex:0 0 auto; display:flex; flex-flow:row; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start;}

.photogallery__viewer{ width:55%; height:100%; position:relative; display:flex; }

.photogallery__viewer__image{max-width:80%; height:auto; margin:auto; overflow:hidden; box-shadow:0 0 25px #111;}

.photogallery{
 
 width:42%; 
 height:93%; 
 position:relative; 
 display:flex; 
 flex-wrap:wrap; 
 justify-content:flex-start; 
 align-content:flex-start; 
 overflow:auto;
 
}


.photogallery__image{
 background-image: url('images/20170819_194526.jpg'); 
 background-position: center;  
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-size:contain; 
 max-height:20%;  
 min-height:20%; 
 flex:0 0 calc(25% - 15px);  
 margin-right:15px; 
 margin-bottom:35px; 
 cursor:pointer;
}

.photogallery__image:hover{
 opacity:0.8;
}

.close{width:3%; cursor:pointer; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; flex:0 0 3%; text-align:center; display:table;  font-size:25px; font-weight:600; }

.close:hover{color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}
```

```html
<div class="photogallery__maincontainer" style="">
  <span style="display:none; cursor:pointer; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; font-size:50px; font-weight:600; position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:320px;">&#129087;</span>
  
    <div class="photogallery__viewer" style="">
   <img class="photogallery__viewer__image" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0025.jpg" style="">
 </div>
 <div class="photogallery" style="">
   <div id="last" class="photogallery__image" style="background-image: url('images/');"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="close" style="">X</span>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is likely wrong with the regex.

This should work instead:

```
bg = bg.split("'")[1];
```

Comment: Then console.log the value and troubleshoot the problem

Comment: I am doing this and apparently it doesn't even go past the first line of code while the other scripts work just fine, what the hell?